# Unity c# Не удается преобразовать "char" в "char*"

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно взять первую букву имени объекта.

```
string GOname = hit.transform.gameObject.name;
string firstleter = new string(GOname[0]);
```

Ошибка возникает во второй строке внутри скобок.
Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: используйте просто string firstleter = GOname[0].ToString();

Comment: ну а конкретно по вашей проблеме. Нужно передавать массив типа char, а не один элемент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Andrey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/315886/andrey) всё верно сказал в комментариях, но почему-то не вынес это в ответ. Итак:

1. Все объекты в C# имеют метод `ToString()`, позволяющий получить строковое представление объекта: `string firstleter = GOname[0].ToString();`
2. Конструктор `string` принимает массив `char`, а Вы ему передаёте один, оттуда и ошибка.